# Blank index.php and admin.php on AWS elastic load balancer

Tags: blank-screen, aws, php.ini

This latest ee launch is going on xyz.com. I've been told:

> This DNS entry points at an AWS elastic load balancer with two linux
>   instances behind it.

I'm not a server person. I don't know how it's set up. Phpinfo seems to have everything I need.

Both my home page (index.php) and admin.php are blank. Yes, I've set $debug = 1. Still blank.

I literally have no idea what to try next. I don't know if it's the files, the server, a path setting or ee itself.

Can someone please suggest something?

Thanks, Amanda

Here's something... if the servers are set up as xx.xx.x.254 (Web1), xx.xx.x.214 (Web2) and xx.xx.x.25 (DB1), phpinfo should still show a mysql section, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Server guy didn't install (or had wrong version of) mysql package.